# Using ctypes to call a function that takes char ** because it writes both the buffer and the pointer

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm trying to call [`iconv(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/iconv) from a Python (3) program, using ctypes.  The C type signature of `iconv` is

```
size_t iconv(iconv_t cd,
             char **inptr, size_t *inbytesleft,
             char **outptr, size_t *outbytesleft);
```

and you are expected to call it like this:

```
char *inp = "abcdef";
char outbuf[16];
char *outp = outbuf;
size_t ibytes = strlen(inbuf);
size_t obytes = sizeof outbuf;

size_t rv = iconv(cd, &inp, &ibytes, &outp, &obytes);
```

It will write to `outbuf`, obviously, and it will also modify all four of the *variables* `inp`, `outp`, `ibytes`, and `obytes` to indicate how far it got with the conversion before running into a problem (if any).  It guarantees not to write to the input string, despite that not being `const`.

Now, naively, you reflect that in `ctypes` like this:

```
iconv = libc.iconv
iconv.restype = ctypes.c_size_t
iconv.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, 
                  ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p),
                  ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t),
                  ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p),
                  ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t)]
```

(`iconv_t` is a typedef for `void *` in the C library I'm testing on) but when I try to *call* that, I get errors:

```
>>> obuf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(16)
>>> obuflen = ctypes.c_size_t(16)
>>> iconv(utf8_to_utf16,
...       ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_char_p(b"abcdef")),
...       ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_size_t(6)),
...       ctypes.byref(obuf),
...       ctypes.byref(obuflen))
ArgumentError: argument 4: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_char_p
    instance instead of pointer to c_char_Array_16
```

Trying to explicitly convert `obuf` to `c_char_p` doesn't work either:

```
>>>  optr = ctypes.c_char_p(obuf)
TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of c_char_Array_16 instance
```

These type names it's using in the error messages don't appear in the manual, and I'm pretty well stumped.  What's the right way to go about this?

(If you are wondering why I would want to do this instead of using Python's built-in encoding converters, the short version is because Python's converters don't support the same set of encodings as [GNU] iconv, nor do they have the `//TRANSLIT` feature.)

Comment: Define a generic pointer type instead of using simple `c_char_p`. For example: `LP_c_char = POINTER(c_char)`. In `argtypes`, use `POINTER(LP_c_char)`. Then you can use `optr = LP_c_char(obuf)` and pass it as `byref(optr)`. The function will modify `optr`.

Comment: FYI, for better type safety you can use a pointer to an opaque struct for `iconv_t`. For example: `class _iconv_t(Structure): pass` and `iconv_t = POINTER(_iconv_t)`. Or in one statement: `iconv_t = POINTER(type('_iconv_t', (Structure,), {}))`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is code which I used to find chars which are converted to '"' with translit. Sorry it is not very polished but I hope it could be still usable for somebody. :)

I needed to run it under python2.6 so I tried to wrote it a little more universal. (2.6 has some gotchas so code could be nicer and simpler under python3)

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")

if sys.version_info[0]>2:
    def unichr(a):
        return chr(a)

LP_c_char2 = ctypes.POINTER( ctypes.c_char_p) 
LP_c_char = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.create_string_buffer(16).__class__)                                                                                                  

get_errno_loc = libc.__errno_location
get_errno_loc.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)

class MyError(OSError):
    def __init__(self, e):
        if sys.version_info[0]<=2:
            super(MyError, self).__init__(e)
        else:
            super().__init__(e)


def errcheck(ret, func, args):
    if ret == -1 or ret == 2**64-1:
        e = get_errno_loc()[0]
        raise MyError(e)
    return ret

iconv_open = libc.iconv_open
iconv_open.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
ret = iconv_open(
    ctypes.c_char_p(b"ISO8859-2//TRANSLIT"), 
    ctypes.c_char_p(b"UTF-8"))

iconv = libc.iconv
iconv.errcheck = errcheck
iconv.restype = ctypes.c_size_t

obuf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(16)
obuflen = ctypes.c_size_t(16)
optr = LP_c_char(obuf)

inp = b'\xe2\x80\x9c'

iconv.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, LP_c_char2, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t),     ctypes.POINTER(LP_c_char), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t)]
r = iconv(ret, LP_c_char2(ctypes.c_char_p(inp)), ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_size_t(len(inp))), ctypes.byref(optr), ctypes.byref(obuflen))

print(obuf.value)

def func(inp = b"bbb"):
    assert len(inp)<16 , "too big input"
    obuf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(16)
    obuflen = ctypes.c_size_t(16)
    optr = LP_c_char(obuf)
    r = iconv(ret, LP_c_char2(ctypes.c_char_p(inp)), ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_size_t(len(inp))), ctypes.byref(optr), ctypes.byref(obuflen))
    return obuf, obuflen, r, obuf.value[:16-obuflen.value]

oo, uu, r, vys = func(b'\xe2\x80\x9c\xe2\x80\x9c')
print(oo.raw, uu, r, vys)

for i in range(sys.maxunicode):
    try:
        oo, uu, r, vys = func(unichr(i).encode('utf-8'))
        if vys==b'"':
            print(i, unichr(i))
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        pass
    except MyError as E:
        pass
        # print("MyError: {E} , {i}".format(E=E, i=i))
```